# Show keyboard when BottomSheet opens

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want the keyboard to appear automatically when certain fragments are open in my application. To this end, I created an extension function `showKeyboard()`:

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard() {
    this.requestFocus()
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
    imm?.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

This function works very well in fragments, but for some reason, it doesn't work in BottomSheets.

Here's how I use it in fragments (this works ✅ ):

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    binding.nickEdit.showKeyboard()
}
```

Here's how I use it in BottomSheet (this doesn't work ❌):

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    binding.searchEdit.showKeyboard()
}
```

I have tried adding `showkeyboard()` function to `onViewCreated()`, but the keyboard still doesn't appear when the BottomSheet opens. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding `windowSoftInputMode` attribute to my BottomSheet style and setting the value to `adjustResize`. Here's the full version of my BottomSheet style:

```
<style name="MyBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/MyBottomsheetStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>

<style name="MyBottomsheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_bottom_sheet</item>
</style>
```